# Import SolverFactory from pyomo.opt or pyomo.environ

Tags: pyomo

I have observed, for example in https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/working_models.html, that sometimes SolverFactory is imported from pyomo.opt and sometimes from pyomo.environ. Is there any difference? Is a matter of legacy vs new syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference: they are the same object.  The examples that import it from `pyomo.opt` are just older and date from before `SolverFactory` was added to the `pyomo.environ` namespace.

The intent behind `pyomo.environ` was to gather the classes and objects most commonly used by users into a single namespace.  This was more of an issue before Pyomo 4.0, when the project was called "Coopr" and was distributed as a series of pseudo-independent packages.  That meant the main namespace (what is now "pyomo") was a "namespace package" and didn't have objects / classes in it.

`pyomo.environ` also takes care of importing and registering the plugins that are scattered around the code base (in particular: solvers, writers, and transformations).  In that sense, it is generally important to always import `pyomo.environ` (or something from `pyomo.environ.*`) as part of any model, otherwise it is likely that the solver you want to use was not registered with the `SolverFactory`.